# Android custom keyboard for measurements

Tags: android, keyboard

I've scoured the net and SO and can't find what I'm hoping to be a simple solution to a problem i have.

I want one activity of my app to include a keyboard which allows the user to input 0-9 "." and then one of 3 selections for "mm" "cm" "m".

Is there a way to override the standard keyboard to provide this limited version or should I just build it into my view - this seems a bit non-standard.

Any ideas?

Comment: Easiest would be to build it yourself instead of overriding the standard keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up just making a custom view with a specialised keyboard on the screen.